# how to do a p4 merge from parent to child at current CL?

Tags: perforce

I am trying to do a p4 merge through command line but none of the arguments I see in the documentation actually seems to work to take the current CL I need to specify it manually with -c. Is there any way to merge from current CL (whatever that is) to child? I thought `p4 merge` without arguments would do it but it is not the caseas I get the `Missing/wrong number of arguments.` Error

Answer (score 2):

The `-c` option specifies the *pending* changelist that the target files will be placed into, not the *submitted* changelist(s) that will be used as the source of the merge.  If this option is not used, files are opened in the *default changelist* (which will become a numbered changelist when you run either `p4 change` or `p4 submit`).

The default behavior of most commands (including `p4 merge`) is to use the latest revisions/changelist.  To merge to the current stream from its parent just do `p4 merge`.  It is not necessary to specify the changelist.  If you do need to specify a changelist, use an optional *revision specifier*, e.g. `p4 merge @someChange`.  (Note: if you're using an old version of Perforce, specifying the child stream is necessary rather than having it inferred as being the one associated with the current workspace -- use `-S currentStream`.)

See `p4 help merge` for more information on what the different flags to `p4 merge` do, and `p4 help revisions` for information on revision specifiers in general.

Comment: thanks @Samwise but as I mentioned I get missing/wrong arguments when using p4 merge command as per se

Comment: You might be on an old version of Perforce, or not using streams.  See `p4 help merge` to get usage information for your server version.  Do `p4 client -o` to see how your client is set up -- do you have a `Stream` (stream in a stream depot) that auto-generates the view, or a manually created `View` (paths in classic depots)?

Comment: we use stream depots and I am running Perforce 2021 ```Helix Visual Client version: P4V/NTX64/2021.1/2075061```

Comment: Run `p4 info` to see what version of the server you're using.  I remember adding the `p4 merge` syntactic sugar sometime around 2016 so I'm guessing your server is at least 5 years out of date.  :)

Comment: Server version: P4D/NTX64/2020.1/2107780 (2021/03/30)

Comment: What does `p4 help merge` say about which arguments are valid?  On a current server `p4 merge [options] [-F] [--from stream] [toFile][revRange]` should be listed as valid usage -- i.e. all arguments optional.

Comment: I just realized when running ```p4 client -o``` that the root shown is wrong it says ```Root:   c:\Users\User ``` but the root of the WS is actually in D drive somehting like ```D:/Project``` how can this be?

Comment: You're using a different workspace from the one you expect, and possibly a different server to boot.  Check your P4CLIENT, or use a command prompt that you launch from P4V (which will set the environment to match whatever you're using in P4V).

Comment: this is what it shows ```p4 help merge

    merge -- Merge one set of files into another

    p4 merge [options] [-F] [--from stream] [toFile][revRange]
    p4 merge [options] fromFile[revRange] toFile```

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that when you ran `p4 merge` and got the usage error, you were passing some extra arguments (hence the error was "unexpected arguments" rather than "missing arguments").  SO isn't a good venue to debug this; I suggest posting on forums.perforce.com where you can post full transcripts of what you're running and get feedback, or email support@perforce.com if you have a support contract.

Comment: I have tried several times and I was not using any arguemtns, but I will do as you said and will write on the perforce forum, thanks for the help!

Comment: ah, I think I figured it out -- you got the error because your second client (the one with the `C:\Users\User` root) is in fact a classic client (hence no current stream, which means you need to specify a mapping some other way).  So once you resolve the config issue things should just work.  :)

Comment: I have change the config file with ```p4 client``` and not it shows the right WS and mapping but yet keep failing :(

Comment: You don't change the config with `p4 client` -- this should be a very simple problem, but things have gone severely off the rails.  You *really* want to be posting on the Perforce forums for help so you can just post `p4 set` output and have someone tell you what command to run to fix things.  :)

Comment: I have posted there already, thanks :)

Comment: nobody seem to care about my post in perforce forums xD. I have used ```p4 stream``` command and whereas in my home PC it returns the right stream (both are using same server and same stream, my home and office PC) the office PC returns ```p4 stream
Must specify a full stream path if not currently using a stream client.```

Comment: the thing is that in P4V it shows the right stream in the stream graph tab and it has always sync and work fine

Comment: ok I got it to work by running ```p4 client``` and setting the stream field manually